# Date/time validation in PHP

Tags: php, validation, date

I'm trying to take individual values for date/time from a form submission and parse them into a date of a certain format.

If validation fails for any reason (e.g. 30th Feb, 13th month, etc) then the result should default to the current time.

```
if (isset($_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['hour'], $_POST['minute']))
{
    $y = $_POST['year'];
    $m = $_POST['month'];
    $d = $_POST['day'];
    $h = $_POST['hour'];
    $i = $_POST['minute'];
    if (checkdate($m, $d, $y))
    {
        if ($h >= 0 && $h <= 23)
        {
            if ($i >= 0 && $i <= 59)
            {
                $str = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d.' '.$h.':'.$i.':00';
                $time = strtotime($str);
            }
            else $time = time();
        }
        else $time = time();
    }
    else $time = time();
}
else $time = time();

$datetime = date('D j M Y - H:i:s T', $time);
echo $datetime;
```

Two things happen which I don't understand:

- If one or more date values are missing, an error appears about checkdate()... I can't see why the validation doesn't just fail at the first if()
- If one or more time values are missing, the end result is the UNIX Epoch?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty value check before execute checkdata

```
<?php
if(!empty($y) && !empty($m) && !empty($d) && !empty($h) && !empty($i))
{
    if (checkdate($m, $d, $y))
    {
        if ($h >= 0 && $h <= 23)
        {
            if ($i >= 0 && $i <= 59)
            {
                $str = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d.' '.$h.':'.$i.':00';
                $time = strtotime($str);
            }
            else $time = time();
        }
        else $time = time();
    }
    else $time = time();
}
else $time = time();

$datetime = date('D j M Y - H:i:s T', $time);
echo $datetime;

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

> If one or more date values are missing, an error appears about checkdate()... I can't see why the validation doesn't just fail at the first if()

Being set and having a valid value are two different things. A variable can be set and contain an empty string or null. Check to make sure those values actually contain values using `empty()`.

> If one or more time values are missing, the end result is the UNIX Epoch?!

If you pass `date()` an invalid second parameter (i.e. a valid unix timestamp) it defaults to the epoch.